# Cardinaly of the power set of $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Cantor established that the set of natural numbers is countable while the set of real numbers is not countable (i.e. $|N| < 2^N$). In other words, there is no bijection between  $N$ and $R$.

> Why can't we have a proof that there is no bijection between the $R$ and its power set ($|R|< 2^R$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can and do.  Cantor's proof works generally between any set and its power set to show that the power set has strictly greater cardinality.  Take any purported bijection $f:A\leftrightarrow P(A)$.  For each element $a \in A$ ask whether it is in $f(a)$  The subset $B=\{a \in A|a \not \in f(A)\}$ is not the image of any element of $A$

Comment: The point that I am not comfortable with is that Cantor proof uses the fact that N is listable. R is not listable.

Comment: Listable is not an issue.  My sketch does not refer to a list, it refers to any claimed bijection.  This one is called [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) which applies to any set.